# How to correctly query the Pizza Ontology with SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, rdfs

This request returns all pizzas with mushroom topping:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>

SELECT ?pizza 
WHERE {
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:Pizza .
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
                            a owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping; 
                            owl:someValuesFrom pizza:MushroomTopping 
                ]
}
```

but I want to list all pizzas with VegetableTopping, which is a subclass of PizzaTopping. Additonally MushroomTopping is a subclassof VegetableTopping. The following query doesn't provided the intended results:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>

SELECT ?pizza 
WHERE {
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:Pizza .
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
                            a owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping; 
                            owl:someValuesFrom pizza:VegetableTopping 
                ]
}
```

Comment: you have to make the topping a variable value, and then state that the variables binds to all subclasses of `VegetableTopping`: `SELECT ?pizza 
WHERE {
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:Pizza .
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
                            a owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping; 
                            owl:someValuesFrom ?topping 
                ] . ?topping rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:VegetableTopping .
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks this was very useful and it worked, except for SeafoodTopping from the ontology. why?

Comment: would you consider `Seafood` being a `Vegetable`? At least I would not. You can also check the class hierarchy of the Pizza ontology, it's a sibling class of `VegetableTopping`

Answer (score 1):

As said by UninformedUser in the comments, you have to make the topping a variable value, and then state that the variables binds to all subclasses of `VegetableTopping` using the `rdfs:subClassOf*` property path.

```
SELECT ?pizza WHERE {
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:Pizza .
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
                           a owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping;
                           owl:someValuesFrom ?topping                  
                           ] .
    ?topping rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:VegetableTopping .
}
```